# Application asking for password

Tags: password

Something is asking me for my password (through a GUI popup) at startup and, if not given, again every half an hour.

I tried to deactivate every program at startup, but still asking.
How can I find what is this program?

I'm using Ubuntu desktop 18.04

EDIT: I tried:

```
while true ; do xlsclients; echo "" ; sleep 10 ; done
```

And I get those processes:

```
gnome-shell
ibus-x11
gsd-power
gsd-xsettings
gsd-wacom
gsd-clipboard
gsd-keyboard
gsd-media-keys
gsd-color
nautilus-desktop
gnome-terminal-server
gnome-software
```

Trying to kill some of these, I figure out that `gsd-*` restart again

Comment: `xlsclients` (in a terminal window) (when the password prompt is open) should help. `xlsclients` is part of the `x11-utils` package.

Comment: you can also install htop (sudo apt install htop) and check which processes actively run on your computer.

Comment: The thing is the window locks every possible action except submit password or cancel action, I can't run any command